# How can I wait for the result from "refiting2" if the app is closed?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

The logic is this: the user writes the text and when the button is pressed, the text is sent using "retrofit2" to the server and the result is returned from the server as text.
But there is a problem, the user can exit the application and the result will not come and will not be saved.

How can I wait for the result from the server if the application is closed to save it?

I tried to use the startForeground service but it requires (Notification) to work. And I would not want to show the user a notification when the application is open.

Comment: One solution if you don't want a notification is to use [WorkManager jobs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager). You'll need something running in the background, since your app is no longer around. You could also do things like saving the pending result, and retrying when the user opens your app again.